# looping through flash and getting active model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to loop through my flash messages but I am getting an active model object as the message.

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
  <%= msg %>
<% end %>

#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007f84c4cdb108 @base=#<User id: nil, email: "cd", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: "$2a$10$lmh2.rb9bAmsQ3lo6SEYqu1f2L1JOVrD8VxmPXJ5Jobx...", remember_token: nil, admin: false, username: nil, password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, provider: nil, uid: nil>, @messages={:email=>["is invalid"], :password=>["is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]}>
```

If the then loop through the object I can get to the messages

```
<% flash.each do |key, msg| %>
    <% msg.each do |k,m| %>
        <%= m %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

is invalid 
is too short (minimum is 6 characters)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or must I do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are populating flash with error object instead of the messages. You can do this in your view to show all the error messages

```
<%= flash[:error].full_messages.join("\n")%>
```

I would advise you to just populate the error messages in flash by doing this in controller

```
flash[:error] = @model.errors.full_messages
```

And in your view you can just do

```
<%= flash[:error] %>
```